# How and why would one call the cockpit of an A330 inside its nose gear bay?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, avionics

According to this A330 call panel diagram,
[image: Airbus A330 call panel diagram]
there is an option to call the nose gear bay with the MECH button. Where is the connection for this in the nose gear bay, and what would it be used for? The closest I can find is in [this video](https://youtu.be/I5qNEkjtJbs?t=410), where some connections to call the cockpit of a Boeing 777 are shown in the forward avionics bay, presumably to help with communication among maintenance personnel. Whether these jacks are similar to the MECH channel on the A330 I do not know.

Comment: I'd hate to be the guy _answering_ that call at FL330!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact it's called the *MECH* channel is a pretty big hint that yes, this is for maintenance personnel.

Ant it's not just the nose wheel bay, there are service interphone connections in [several locations](https://www.scribd.com/document/376297113/A330-200-Communications).

[image]